# Importing a module causes an error, but separating them to two and then importing doesn't, why?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm trying to find out for myself how I could work around the problem I recently asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150156/how-load-a-model-and-its-constants-through-just-importing-a-module) and I come across a potential solution, but I honestly don't understand why it works, and why the other doesn't.

For context, `model` requires variables `a` and `b` to be defined before being successfully loaded and defined in a module. Otherwise, it throws an error: `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

Starting off with `model.py`:

```py
import pickle

from tensorflow import keras

# loads and returns the variables needed by model
def load_model_vars():
    return pickle.load(open('./file.pkl', 'rb'))

# loads and returns the model
def load_model():
    return keras.models.load_model('./model.h5')
```

Now to minimally reproduce and identify the problem I created a new module, `foo.py`:

```py
from model import load_model_vars, load_model

# goal here is to supposedly expose only the model to other modules
a, b = load_model_vars()
globals()['model'] = load_model()
```

I then created another module to import `foo.py` into, let's name it `bar.py`:

```py
import foo

# just checks if the model is defined
foo.model.summary()
```

Which for some reason throws the formerly mentioned `NameError`. *Why?* The variables are defined, it was executed in order(load variables first, then model), and even if I change `a, b` to `globals()['a'], globals()['b']`, `import foo` to `from foo import *` or `from foo import a, b` or even combinations of any of these, it always arrives into this error.

But when I introduce another module, say, `baz.py`, that contains these two lines:

```py
from model import load_model_vars

a, b = load_model_vars()
```

Then import it to `bar.py`:

```py
from baz import a, b

import foo

# just checks if the model is defined
foo.model.summary()
```

With `foo.py` unchanged, or with `a, b = load_model_vars()` commented out:

```py
from model import load_model_vars, load_model

# goal here is to supposedly expose only the model to other modules
# a, b = load_model_vars()
globals()['model'] = load_model()
```

It successfully loads the freaking model! Why? What's this sorcery underneath the import function? What actually happens under the hood?